# Order By date of object and by latest date of related object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.4

Consider two following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Reply(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='replies')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Now I want to order by `created_at` of model `Post` and with `created_at` of model `Reply` (it has highest priority).

Lets suppose, I have two posts p1 whose created time is greater than p2, but p2 has the reply whose created date is greater than p1. So p2 should come first and then p1.

I have tried to do that in the manager, but it does not gives me my desired ordering:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(PostManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(
            reply_date=Max('replies__created_at')
        ).order_by('-reply_date', '-created_at')
```

Turns out to be the problem is this:

- There is a situation when the newer post doesn't have any replies yet, so Max('replies__created_at') is None
- That would make all the post without any reply to be listed after all posts with replies.

Any help??

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have done it like this:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def posts_for_user(self, user):
        qs = super(PostManager, self).get_query_set().filter(user__id=user.id)
        qs_a = qs.filter(replies__isnull=False).annotate(
            latest_date=Max('replies__created_at')
        )

        qs_b = qs.filter(replies__isnull=True).extra(
            select={'latest_date': 'walls_post.created_at'}
        )

        return sorted(chain(qs_a, qs_b),
            key=attrgetter('latest_date'), reverse=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    sorted = PostManager()
```

Now I can do:

```
posts = Post.sorted.posts_for_user(user)
```

If any one has the better approach please share it.